# Testing for preceding-sibling and matching descendant using xsl:key

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have a problem that I believe I need to use grouping using xsl:key to solve, but I am at a loss as to the correct syntax. For the following XML, when I process each `<a/>` element I need to test to see if

1. the element has a preceding-sibling `<markerStart/>` element and a descendant `</markerEnd>` element with the same id.

   - By "preceding-sibling" I mean that there must not be an `<a/>` between the current element and the `<markerStart/>` , so the `<a/>` marked `<!-- # 5 -->` should return false, while  the `<a/>` marked `<!-- # 1 -->` and the first `<a/>` following the element marked `<!-- # 2a -->` should return true.
   - By "descendant"  I mean that there must not be an `<a/>` descendant before the `<markerEnd/>` , so the `<a/>` marked `<!-- # 0 -->` and the first `<a/>` following the element marked `<!-- # 2b -->` should return false.
2. OR the element has a descendant `<markerStart/>` element and a descendant `</markerEnd>` element with the same id.

   - By "descendant"  I mean that there must not be an `<a/>` descendant before the `<markerEnd/>`.

For the following XML, I would expect the nodes marked with `<!-- # 1 -->`, `<!-- # 2a -->`, and `<!-- # 4 -->` to return true.

```
<root>
    <a><!-- # 0 -->
        <b>
            <c>
                <markerStart id="a1"/>
                <a> <!-- # 1 -->
                    <b>
                        <c>
                        <markeEnd id="a1"/>
                        </c>
                    </b>
                </a>
                <markerStart id="a2"/><!-- # 2a -->
                <markerStart id="a3"/><!-- # 2b -->
                <a><!-- # 2 -->
                    <b>
                        <c>
                        <markeEnd id="a2"/>
                            <a><!-- # 3 -->
                                <b>
                                    <c>
                                        <markeEnd id="a3"/>
                                    </c>
                                </b>
                            </a>
                        </c>
                    </b>
                </a>
                <markerStart id="a5"/>
                <a><!-- # 4 -->
                    <markerStart id="a4"/>
                    <b>
                        <c>
                        <markeEnd id="a4"/>
                        </c>
                    </b>
                </a>
                <a><!-- # 5 -->
                    <b>
                        <c>
                        <markeEnd id="a5"/>
                        </c>
                    </b>
                </a>
            </c>
        </b>
    </a>
</root>
```

I need to used XSL 1.0 for this problem. Any help is more than appreciated.

Comment: A little clarification: `<markerStart id="a2"/><!-- # 2a -->` isn't an `a` element.

Comment: @Alejandro: Yes, in this case '<!-- # 2a -->' is meant to relate to the '<a/>' element marked with the '<!-- # 2 -->' comment. In my attempt to be clear I knew I was going to confuse someone with that.

Comment: And why outermost `a` woulnd't be selected?

Comment: @Alejandro: There is no '<markeEnd/>' as a descendant that is not within an embedded '<a/>'. As another example, the '<a/>' marked '<!--# 2 -->' would be true for '<markerStart id="a2"/>', but false for '<markerStart id="a3"/>'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="kMarkerStartByFollowingMarkeEnd"
             match="markerStart"
             use="generate-id(following::markeEnd[1])"/>
    <xsl:key name="kMarkeEndByAncestorA"
             match="markeEnd"
             use="generate-id(ancestor::a[1])"/>
    <xsl:template match="a[key('kMarkeEndByAncestorA',
                               generate-id()
                           )[1]/@id =
                           key('kMarkerStartByFollowingMarkeEnd',
                               generate-id(key('kMarkeEndByAncestorA',
                                               generate-id()
                                           )[1])
                           )/@id]">
        <xsl:copy-of select="comment()"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<!-- # 1 --><!-- # 2 --><!-- # 4 -->
```

Comment: @Alejandro: Sorry my description is not as clear as I would have liked, but "#0" should not be matched. See my comment above.